# Data not getting posted to server while using Volley library in android

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I am trying to `Post` some `JsonObject` to a server using `Volley` library in android. I doubt that the `getparams` method is not being called and my data is not getting posted. Can anyone guide me step by step where I am going wrong.  My codes are as follows:

```
          case R.id.bt_search:



         try {
            jObj.put("FromDate", "04-10-2014");
            jObj.put("Todate", "04-11-2014");
            jObj.put("BillNumber", bill);
            jObj.put("Status", "NotClosed");
            jObj.put("OrderType", "1,2,3" /* Ordertype */);
            Log.i("json data on clicking search", "" + jObj);
            makeJsonObjReq(jObj);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;


  private void makeJsonObjReq(final JSONObject jObj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Method.POST,
            "myurl",
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("server Response", arg0.toString());

                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < arg0.length(); i++) {

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    VolleyLog.d("Error msg from server",
                            "Error: " + arg0.getMessage());

                }

            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("data", jObj.toString());

            //return params;
             return super.getParams();

        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.getHeaders();
        }

    };

    com.cashier.volley_helper.AppController.getInstance()
            .addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    rq.add(jsonObjReq);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify getParams() method

```
private void makeJsonObjReq(final JSONObject jObj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Method.POST,
            "myurl",
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("server Response", arg0.toString());

                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < arg0.length(); i++) {

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    VolleyLog.d("Error msg from server",
                            "Error: " + arg0.getMessage());

                }

            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Map<String, String> params = super.getParams();
             if( params==null)
             params =new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("data", jObj.toString());

           return params;
         }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.getHeaders();
        }

    };

    com.cashier.volley_helper.AppController.getInstance()
            .addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    rq.add(jsonObjReq);
}
```

Comment: trying this code gives me the following error: `[1] 4.onErrorResponse: Error msg from server`

Comment: have you put "myurl" as myUrl?

Comment: and if i put a log in it to show the params der is not output visible in d log

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom request class like this

```html
public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

 @Override
 public Entry getCacheEntry() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return super.getCacheEntry();
 }

 @Override
 public String getCacheKey() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return super.getCacheKey();
 }

 private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
 private Map<String, String> params;

 public CustomRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
   Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
  super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
  this.listener = reponseListener;
  this.params = params;
 }

 public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
   Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
  super(method, url, errorListener);
  this.listener = reponseListener;
  this.params = params;
 }

 @Override
 protected Map<String, String> getParams()
   throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
  System.out.println(params);
  return params;
 };

 @Override
 protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
  try {
   String jsonString = new String(response.data,
     HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
   return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
     HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
  } catch (JSONException je) {
   return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  listener.onResponse(response);
 }
}
```

and use it like this

```html
WeakHashMap<String, String> params = new WeakHashMap<String, String>();
  params.put("product_id", DetailsFragment.product_id);
  System.out.println("Printing the Jsoparams" + params);
  CustomRequest request = new CustomRequest(Method.POST, url, params,
    this.createMyReqSuccessListener(),
    this.createMyReqErrorListener()) {

  };
  volley.addToRequestQueue(request, DETAILS, true);
```

```html
private Response.Listener<JSONObject> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
  return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Log.d("response from services", response.toString());
    
//Parse the response here

    

  };
 }

 private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener() {
  return new Response.ErrorListener() {
   @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    System.out.println("Printing the Error" + error);
    System.out.println(VolleyErrorHelper.getMessage(error));
   }

  };
 }
```